# performance.now using onnxruntime for sequential and parallel execution modes

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm using [Onnxruntime](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime) in NodeJS to execute onnx converted models in cpu backend. I run model inference in parallel using Promise.allSettled:

```
var promises = sequences.map(seq => self.inference(self.session, self.tokenizer, seq));
results = (await Promise.allSettled(promises)).filter(p => p.status === "fulfilled").map(p => p.value);
```

running this class instance method `inference` that calls a static method `Util.performance.now`

```
  ONNX.prototype.inference = async function (session, tokenizer, text) {
        const default_labels = this._options.model.default_labels;
        const labels = this._options.model.labels;
        const debug = this._options.debug;
        try {
            const encoded_ids = await tokenizer.tokenize(text);
            if (encoded_ids.length === 0) {
                return [0.0, default_labels];
            }
            const model_input = ONNX.create_model_input(encoded_ids);
            const start = Util.performance.now();
            const output = await session.run(model_input, ['output_0']);
            const duration = Util.performance.now(start).toFixed(1);

            const sequence_length = model_input['input_ids'].size;
            if (debug) console.log("latency = " + duration + "ms, sequence_length=" + sequence_length);
            const probs = output['output_0'].data.map(ONNX.sigmoid).map(t => Math.floor(t * 100));

            const result = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                const t = [labels[i], probs[i]];
                result[i] = t;
            }
            result.sort(ONNX.sortResult);

            const result_list = [];
            for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                result_list[i] = result[i];
            }
            return [parseFloat(duration), result_list];
        } catch (e) {
            return [0.0, default_labels];
        }
    }//inference
```

the timing is wrong and summed up.
The `performance` object looks like

```
Util = {
   performance: {
      now: function (start) {
          if (!start) {
              return process.hrtime();
          }
          var end = process.hrtime(start);
          return Math.round((end[0] * 1000) + (end[1] / 1000000));
      }
  }
}
```

and it used in the usual way

```
// this runs parallel
const start = Util.performance.now();
// computation
const duration = (Util.performance.now() - start).toFixed(1);
```

Now, within the `performance` fun the `start` and `end` variables scope is local, so what happens using `Promise.allSettled`? I would expect that timing would be correct due to the local scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timing mechanics are correct, but when `session.run` is called, it will initiate some asynchronous API (non-JavaScript) while already returning the pending promise object. This will allow other executions of `inference` to call `session.run` as well, leading to a state where the asynchronous API is dealing with several such requests concurrently, and so the *same* slices of time are counted in multiple execution contexts of `inference`. These requests may even end at moments in time that are quite close. When that happens, one after the other executions of `inference` resume with the code that ends the timing (setting their `duration` variables). It is clear that these durations can and probably will *overlap* each other.

To visualise it for 3 executions of `inference`, you could have this:

```
   start-----------------------------start+duration
      start-----------------------------start+duration
         start------------------------------start+duration

 time ----->
```

If you don't want this parallelism, you should not make all calls of `inference` at almost the same time, but wait with each next execution until the previous one is resolved:

```
for (let seq of sequences) {
     let value = await self.inference(self.session, self.tokenizer, seq));
     // ...
}
```

This way executions of the asynchronous part of `session.run` will not overlap, and will not suffer performance because of that concurrency. I would expect timings to be more like this:

```
   start---------------start+duration
                       start-------------start+duration
                                         start------------start+duration

 time ----->
```

Now timeslices will not be counted more than once, even though the total duration of the whole process will likely be longer.

Note that the behaviour has nothing to to with `Promise.allSettled`, because you'll get those outputs anyway, even if you remove that `Promise.allSettled` call from your program.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's definitively correct, `session.run` will call the `onnxruntime` method `run` of their [ort module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/onnxruntime-node) that is this one https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/blob/master/js/node/src/inference_session_wrap.h#L50, so it's native code in fact.

Comment: I also confirm that using `for` async loop the time overlap will work correctly. That was my default implementation, that for performance reasons I'm turning parallel in some cases.

Comment: I digged a bit into the execution provided by onnxruntime, and came out with another question, that is "slightly" connected to this (due to the `sequential` or `parallel` nature of the two approaches exposed in the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72117675/onnxruntime-nodejs-set-intraopnumthreads-and-interopnumthreads-by-execution-mode